error: file /boot/vmlinuz-6.6-x86_64' not found error: you need to load kernel first

After installing updates when I tried to restart the system it was stuck herestrong text

use a live cd or usb of your Linux distribution to boot into a live environment. This allows you to access your file system and perform repairs

If your GRUB boot menu includes an option to select a different kernel versio (often in a sub-menu titled "Advanced options for "), try booting with the second-newest kernel. Then see if your root/boot filesystems might be about 100% full; if so, try and free up some space, then tell your package manager to reinstall the newest kernel package.
